# Using Rally's REST API to retrieve User Stories for a project

Tags: xsd, rally

I am tyring to retrieve the details of all User Stories for a specific project. I am using the REST URL:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/hierarchicalrequirement?project={Rally_REST_URL_for_the_project}&fetch=true

I am using JAXB to unmarshal the XML response. However, the result consists of objects of type DomainObjectType and hence I cannot cast them into HierarchicalRequirementType - in fact the data pertaining to User Stories are not retrievable.

Is there any other way of doing this? I got the XML Schema from the Rally Help pages, and I do not see any way to do it other than make N+1 requests - which I would like to avoid.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Rally support for a validation of their XML Schema. Will post again once they get back to me.

--A few days later--

Thanks to everyone for their efforts.

Apparently, the XML Schema is meant for SOAP and not REST, although it can be used for REST too in some cases.

I have to modify Schema for my requirement - something I am working on now.

Comment: Dave is right that using the REST toolkit will make your life easier in many ways. Does the tool you are using generate code representing the objects based off of an initial request?

It feels like you are trying to use the REST data in a SOAP like manner.

Comment: @CharlesFerentchak I am using Apache Camel for rapid integration. I like to see all of the Camel route at once, so I prefer using the "http(s)" end-point provided by Camel. If using the REST toolkit is the only way, I will try it, but as I said, I would like to "read" the entire route like a sentence, which is why I prefer using the REST URL directly.

Comment: Gotcha, I don't know that technology at all. Wish I could be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

kind of roundabout answer - we have a beta/labs Java REST toolkit you could try here: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

That might be worth a try to help move some of that along.